# Remove all rows in a Pandas DataFrame where a column is True

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to filter values out of a Pandas dataframe, but have Googled and ChatGPT'd to no avail:

why does

```
x1 = df[df!=True]
x2 = df[df==True]
```

result in 2 dataframes, each with the same shape as the original? How can I filter this dataframe into the parts that are True and those that are not.?

Ultimately, I want to do this filtering on a dataframe with several columns, so what I really want to do is more lke:

```
x1 = df[df['col1']!=True]
x2 = df[df['col1']==True]
```

Comment: you said "this" dataframe, but didn't include a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an example like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

# df!=True checks for each value in the DataFrame if the value is equal to True (it matches on 1 because 1 is equivalent to True (and False equivalent to 0) when using "==" and "!="
>>> df!=True 
       A     B
0  False  True
1   True  True
2   True  True

# df[df!=True] gets the values which are True in df!=True, and doesn't get anything for the ones which are false (hence A0 being NaN)
>>> df[df!=True]
     A  B
0  NaN  4
1  2.0  5
2  3.0  6

# this is similar to example #1, but only looks at column 'A'
>>> df['A']!=True
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

To filter to the rows where column 'A' == True

```
>>> df[df['A']!=True]
   A  B
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Pandas interpets this as you wanting to filter the rows, so it takes the values from the previous example, and filters the rows to the ones which return True. If you only want the values which are actually True (i.e. don't match on `1`s), you can use `is`, as in

```
1 is True # False
```

Comment: I want to  remove all rows where the value in column A is True

Comment: @user1245262 the last example `df[df['A']!=True]` does that

Comment: Yup ... I just read to the bottom and saw that ... Thx

Comment: Don't use `df[df['A']!=True]` if you already have a boolean column but rather `df[~df['A']]`